# Shell execute from Ruby

Tags: ruby, windows, shell

Assume, I have a file 'text_file.txt' within my .rb script. How do I execute a default windows program for that file from the Ruby?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From IRB:

```
system "start text_file.txt"
```

From a shell:

```
ruby -e 'system "start text_file.txt"'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `system` command, like in

```
ruby -e 'system "ipconfig"'
```