# I want to make a shell command program in ruby for windows but everything is in linux

Tags: ruby, windows, shell

I have a ruby program named options that I want to run from the command line with a few options like

```
options -add 400
options -sub 600
options -h
```

I am already using optparse to interpret the commands but I want to run the program as its own script, but have to run it as

```
ruby options -add 400
```

I've looked it up and found some answers like [How to create a shell command supporting Ruby?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9710337/how-to-create-a-shell-command-supporting-ruby/9710596#9710596) which seems to be linux and I'm not sure of part of the explanation like which bin to put in, or answers like [Shell execute from Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1527003/shell-execute-from-ruby) whose answer still requires ruby in the command. Can anyone explain how to do this in more depth, or direct me to a source that explains it without relying on a linux platform?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that you have ruby in your `PATH` on Windows couln't you just create wrapper script and place it in folder present at your `PATH`?

```
ruby options %*
```

Comment: Ok, that sounds good. But I dont know what that means. I am a very new developer which I think is my issue

Comment: If it gives any context, I have altered my PATH once by following a step by step set of instructions that were akin to magic

Comment: Here you have [instructions how to modify your path in windows](http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch000549.htm), you should be certain that on this path will be the ruby executable and folder where your wrapper will be located.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have thought about to make it as gem ? There is a simple guide http://guides.rubygems.org/, then you can make the gem which will be working on linux and windows too.  I don't know if you know but when I did software avaible under shell or bash I used slop (https://github.com/injekt/slop) it is very convenient the gem. Please see the source of slop, because it is an example of gem, all structure and necessary files to build the gem.

Comment: I did look into making it a gem, but I was under the impressions that my command would still be 'ruby "program name" -add' and I'm looking to drop the ruby part of that. Feel free to tell me if I'm wrong or point be in the right direction as this is the second program I've made without following a tutorial

Comment: Frankly speaking, I think the simplest way is to make it as gem, then you get 'program name - parameters' but it lose your idea to executable it by 'ruby "program name" -add'.